# MS Access Select query. show either a match or the not match

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, inner-join

I am putting together a select query in the query builder.

I have two tables joined at Customer ID, one data table and one reference table. The select query will display points of the data and some data from the reference table based on what data is present. 
as example:

```
Data table
Customer ID    Batch ID    Order Number    Address    Warehouse
1234           1111        6546            place1     Ware1     
1234           2222        6547            place1     Ware2 
1235           3333        6548            place2     Ware3 
1236           4444        6549            place2     Ware4 
1237           5555        6550            place2     Ware5 
1238           6666        6551            place2     Ware6

Reference table
Customer ID    CustomerName   Warehouse   Account
1234           Cust1                      151515 
1234           Cust1          Ware2       151516 
1235           Cust2                      454545 
1236           Cust3                      464646 
1237           Cust4                      474747 
1238           Cust5                      484848
```

The constraint I have is I do not have access to a comprehensive list of all the different customers warehouses to fill the reference table but because most customers use the same account for all their warehouses its not super important they be filled in. There is however one customer who has a separate account for a particular warehouse. I would rather not have a solution which caters to the one customer but rather can work with any customer who comes up in the future who has a particular separate account.

The kind of field I'm looking to make is something which will display an account if either the warehouse matches or if it doesn't match(because its blank). I've been wracking my brain. I'm not sure there is a solution to this but I thought I'd pose it to the community.

*EDIT*
Here is the sample output i'm looking for if you give the data table and run the query. I've also updated the account column with actual values so its less confusing

```
Query Results
CustomerName    Order Number    Account    Address
Cust1           6546            151515     Place1
Cust1           6547            161616     Place1
Cust2           6548            454545     Place2
Cust3           6549            464646     Place3
Cust4           6550            474747     Place4
Cust5           6551            484848     Place5
```

Comment: Please show us the output that you would expect for this sample data.

Comment: Is "Account1", "Account2" literally the actual values in field? These are the only possible values? Or are there actually unique account numbers?

Comment: Is there a Customers table with a unique record for each customer? If so, probably should not duplicate CustomerName into Reference.

Comment: the accounts are unique. I've updated the table to reflect that. also provided sample output.

Answer (score 0):

DLookup domain aggregate function might get what you want. Consider:

```
SELECT Data.CustomerID, Data.BatchID, Data.OrderNumber, Data.Address, Data.Warehouse, 
Nz(DLookUp("Account","Reference","CustomerID=" & [CustomerID] & " AND Warehouse='" & [Warehouse] & "'"), 
   DLookup("Account","Reference","CustomerID=" & [CustomerID] & " AND Nz([Warehouse])<>'" & [Warehouse] & "'")) AS Acct
FROM Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward until you have to eliminate the Null matches when there is a matching warehouse.  Here is one way using a sub-query to eliminate the warehouse Null matches:

```
SELECT tblData.[Customer ID], tblData.[Batch ID], tblData.[Order Number], tblData.Address, tblData.Warehouse, tblRef.Account
FROM tblData LEFT JOIN tblRef ON tblData.[Customer ID]=tblRef.[Customer ID]
WHERE (tblData.Warehouse=tblRef.[Warehouse] AND tblRef.Warehouse Is Not Null)
   OR (tblData.Warehouse Not In (SELECT tblRef.Warehouse FROM tblRef WHERE tblRef.Warehouse Is Not Null AND tblRef.[Customer ID] = tblData.[Customer ID]) AND tblRef.Warehouse Is Null);
```

So doing a left join on just [Customer ID], include records where the warehouse matches and is not null, and also include records that have no matching warehouse and additionally have no matching warehouse existing for a given [Customer ID] (these are itemized in the sub-query for each [Customer ID])

Result is:

```
Customer ID    Batch ID    Order Number    Address    Warehouse    Account
1234           1111        6546            place1     Ware1        Account1     
1234           2222        6547            place1     Ware2        Account2 
1235           3333        6548            place2     Ware3        Account1 
1236           4444        6549            place2     Ware4        Account1 
1237           5555        6550            place2     Ware5        Account1 
1238           6666        6551            place2     Ware6        Account1
```